# Detecting a window total row count

Tags: applescript

I am new to applescripting and I would like to determine the best practice of iterating through rows in a window.  But I do not know how to throw an error once all of the rows are compared.
Currently I set a 'hard value' of 3 (because I only have 2 rows to check)  but I may have more than 3 rows and I want it to fail once it checks all of the rows in the window. 
What can I replace the code line 'if TheRow is equal to 3' below to detect that it has iterated through all of the rows?

```
  set ReadDBPluginName to value of (text field 1 of row TheRow of table 1 of scroll area 1 of tab group 1 of window "Plugins Manager" of process "OSX")
        if ReadDBPluginName is not equal NewDBPluginName then
        set TheRow to TheRow + 1
        if TheRow is equal to 3
            error "Plugin Name " & NewDBPluginName & " does not exist"
        end if
```

Comment: You should try and supply more specific details about what application you're using, and provide a complete sample of code that compiles.  Your code snippet doesn't compile because `text field` and `process` are unknown identifiers.  Also, `TheRow` is an undefined variable.  Essentially, it's impossible for someone to test and provide you with effective help to your problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Despite what I wrote in my comment against your question (which remains good advice for any future posts to help get you the best help), I *might* be able to provide you with a solution, bearing in mind that it comes straight off the top of my head and hasn't been tested in any capacity.

It looks like you're iterating through a series of `UI elements` grouped into `row` objects, each of which contains a `text field` that you wish to retrieve the `value` of, and compare it to some pre-existing string (`NewDBPluginName`).

Working along this premise, you can do away with any `repeat` loop you're already using, and read the value of every `text field 1` of every `row` at once.  Then, simply check to see if this list of values contains `NewDBPluginName`:

```
    tell application "System Events" to ¬
        set ReadDBPluginNames to the value of ¬
            text field 1 of ¬
            rows of ¬
            table 1 of ¬
            scroll area 1 of ¬
            tab group 1 of ¬
            window "Plugins Manager" of process "OSX"

    if NewDBPluginName is not in ReadDBPluginNames then ¬
        error "Plugin Name " & NewDBPluginName & " does not exist"
```